# Finding maximum in O(logn) time?

Tags: java, max, divide-and-conquer

I've always taken it for granted that iterative search is the go-to method for finding maximum values in an unsorted list.

The thought came to me rather randomly, but in a nutshell: I believe I can accomplish the task in O(logn) time with n being the input array's size.

The approach piggy-backs on merge sort: divide and conquer.

Step 1: divide the findMax() task to two sub-tasks `findMax(leftHalf)` and `findMax(rightHalf)`. This division should be finished in `O(logn)` time.

Step 2: merge the two maximum candidates back up. <strike>Each layer in this step should take constant time `O(1)`, and there are, per the previous step, `O(logn)` such layers. So it should also be done in `O(1) * O(logn) = O(logn)` time (pardon the abuse of notation).</strike> This is so wrong. Each comparison is done in constant time, but there are `2^j/2` such comparisons to be done (2^j pairs of candidates at level j-th).

Thus, the whole task should be completed in <strike>`O(logn)` time.</strike> `O(n)` time.

However, when I try to time it, I get results that clearly reflect a linear `O(n)` running time.

> size = 100000000          max = 0          time = 556
>
> size = 200000000          max = 0          time = 1087
>
> size = 300000000          max = 0          time = 1648
>
> size = 400000000          max = 0          time = 1990
>
> size = 500000000          max = 0          time = 2190
>
> size = 600000000          max = 0          time = 2788
>
> size = 700000000          max = 0          time = 3586

How come?

Here's the code (I left the arrays uninitialized to save on pre-processing time, the method, as far as I'd tested it, accurately identifies the maximum value in unsorted arrays):

```
public static short findMax(short[] list) {
    return findMax(list, 0, list.length);
}

public static short findMax(short[] list, int start, int end) {
    if(end - start == 1) {
        return list[start];
    }
    else {
        short leftMax = findMax(list, start, start+(end-start)/2);
        short rightMax = findMax(list, start+(end-start)/2, end);
        return (leftMax <= rightMax) ? (rightMax) : (leftMax);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int j=1; j < 10; j++) { 
        int size = j*100000000; // 100mil to 900mil
        short[] x = new short[size];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int max = findMax(x);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("size = " + size + "\t\t\tmax = " + max + "\t\t\t time = " + (end - start));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should count the number of comparisons that actually take place :

In the final step, after you find the maximum of the first n/2 numbers and last n/2 nubmers, you need 1 more comparison to find the maximum of the entire set of numbers.

On the previous step you have to find the maximum of the first and second groups of n/4 numbers and the maximum of the third and fourth groups of n/4 numbers, so you have 2 comparisons.

Finally, at the end of the recursion, you have n/2 groups of 2 numbers, and you have to compare each pair, so you have n/2 comparisons.

When you sum them all you get :

1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n/2 = n-1 = O(n)

Comment: Shame on me, I just assumed that every layer is done in constant time since comparison is quick (quicker than merging two arrays in merge_sort, I thought), and I forgot that there are 2^j/2 comparisons to be done on each layer.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed create `log(n)` layers.

But at the end of the day, you still go through each element of every created bucket. Therefore you go through every element. So overall you are still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

With Eran's answer, you already know what's wrong with your reasoning.

But anyway, there is a theorem called the Master Theorem, which aids in the running time analysis of recursive functions.

It verses on the following equation:

```
T(n) = a*T(n/b) + O(n^d)
```

Where T(n) is the running time for a problem of size n.

In your case, the recurrence equation would be `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(1)` So `a=2`, `b=2`, and `d=0`. That is the case because, for each n-sized instance of your problem, you break it into 2 (a) subproblems, of size n / 2 (b), and combines them in O(1) = O(n^0).

The master theorem simply states three cases:

if `a = b^d`, then the total running time is `O(n^d*log n)`

if `a < b^d`, then the total running time is `O(n^d)`

if `a > b^d`, then the total running time is `O(n^(log a / log b))`

Your case matches the third, so the total running time is O(n^(log 2 / log 2)) = `O(n)`

It is a nice exercise to try to understand the reason behind these three cases. They are merely the cases for which:

1st) We do the same amount total work for each recursion level (this is the case of mergesort), so we only multiply the merging time, O(n^d), by the number of levels, log n.

2nd) We do less work for the second recursion level than for the first, and so on. Therefore the total work is basically the one for the last merge step (first recursion level), O(n^d).

3rd) We do more work for deeper levels (your case), so the running time is O(number of leaves in the recursion tree). In your case you have n leaves for the deeper recursion level, so O(n).

There are some short videos on a Stanford cousera course which are very nice to explain the Master Method, available https://www.coursera.org/course/algo. I believe you can always preview the course, even if not enrolled.

Comment: Fancy you should mention the master method. I would have applied it if I had doubted my intuition more than I did. What I got from the master method instead is the intuition for the three cases like you summarized, and like I commented above, I completely forgot about the proliferation of the sub tasks, keeping in mind only the simplicity of the comparison task.